# Saving data to multiple related tables using spring data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm, persistence

I have a requirement to save data into 5 related tables. Assume those tables are A,B,C,D and E. Relationships between those tables are depicted below. For these kinds of scenarios, is it right way to build complete entity graph once and save it using cascade save? Or We can have an orchestrator layer and saving individual entities by calling respective service/repository layers?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

This usually depends on how you structure your "bounded context". Are A, B, C, D, E all part of the same bounded context? Is A a domain aggregate?

If the answer to both is yes, then I'd say save with cascades.